# Query about 2-parameter Lambda

Tags: lambda

In the following code, I am missing how the compiler knows k maps to musos, and why v is auto incrementing:

```
string[] musos = { "David Gilmour", "Rick Wright", "Roger Waters", "Nick Mason" };
int[] keys = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 };

var sorted = musos.Select((k, v) => new { Value = k, Key = keys[v] })
    .OrderBy(k => k.Key)
    .Select(v => v.Value.Split().Last())

foreach (var item in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The code works perfectly, returning:

> Gilmour Mason Waters Wright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, let's go to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector
)
```

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating
>   the element's index.

So in you select, you've got the element (k) and its index(v).

So

- David Gilmour(k)  with 0(v) (index of David Gilmour in musos array)
- Rick Wright(k) with 1(v) (index of Rick Wright in musos array)
- etc.

And your code works, because keys array is at least as long as musos array, so

```
keys[0] = 1 //  0 = v
keys[1] = 4 // 1 = v
keys[2] = 3 // 2 = v
keys[3] = 2 // 3 = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in that case the Select takes a Func delegate to which it passes each element of the IEnumerable as a key, as well as the position of the element in the enumerable. In your case the elements are strings, from the musos array.

The following code:

```
string[] musos = { "David Gilmour", "Rick Wright", "Roger Waters", "Nick Mason" };
int[] keys = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 };

musos.Select((k, v) => new { Value = k, Key = keys[v] })
```

Can be interpreted as:

```
musos.Select((Func<string, int, ANONYMOUS_TYPE>)delegate(string k, int v){
                   return new ANONYMOUS_TYPE() { Value = k, Key = keys[v] };
             });
```

Above, the `ANONYMOUS_TYPE` type is just a place-holder for an anonymous type generated automatically by the compiler to represent and hold the objects returned by your lambda expression which have two public properties: `Value` of type `string` and `Key` of type `int`. This type might look like this:

```
class ANONYMOUS_TYPE
{
    public ANONYMOUS_TYPE()
    {
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

You can now imagine the implementation of Select in that case:

```
IEnumerable<ANONYMOUS_TYPE> Select<string, ANONYMOUS_TYPE>(IEnumerable<string> musos, Func<string, int, ANONYMOUS_TYPE> selector)
{
    int pos = 0; 
    var results = new List<ANONYMOUS_TYPE>();
    foreach(string k in musos)
    {
        results.add(selector(k, pos));
        pos++;
    }
    return (IEnumerable<ANONYMOUS_TYPE>)results;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the first param (k) is expected to match the enumeration. But why is v auto incrementing? What is mapping it to the element number?

Comment: Oops, I was missing a type param in the Func<>. The v is set to the position of element from the enumerable. It's again set internally by the Select method.